# Java Client for WCF on HTTPS

Tags: java, wcf, iis, https, certificate

I can't figure out how to proceed for the next scenario.

I have a WCF service up and running with security like this:

```
<binding name="SSLBinding">
   <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     <!--<message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>-->
   </security>
 </binding>
```

I was able to make a dummy ceritificate in the IIS 5.0, so this WCF can be exposed on HTTPS.

Finally using a .Net client I can communicate with the Service, something like this:

```
private void randomMethod
    {
        //This is necesary, cause the certificate isn´t valid
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler);            

            RefHTTPS.GestionesServiceClient service = new RefHTTPS.GestionesServiceClient();                

            richTextBox1.Text = service.version();                            
    }

    public static bool IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

ISSUE: When I try to do this on a Java client I get Exceptions.

Someone has been able to do something like this, I need some guidance here.

I read a lot of posts on the web, but nothing works for me.

---

Edit (merged from additional content from OP, was posted as a question and flagged):

This is the full config (it has a config tag, but isn't showing):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">          
    </compilation>              
</system.web>  

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
```

```
 <binding name="SSLBinding">
   <security mode="Transport">
     <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
   </security>
 </binding>
```

```
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="https://x.x.x.x"/>
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>

<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="WSGestiones.GestionesServiceBehavior" name="WSGestiones.GestionesService">
      <endpoint address="https://x.x.x.x/GestionesWS/GestionesService.svc"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLBinding" contract="WSGestiones.IGestionesService">            
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />              
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="https://x.x.x.x/GestionesWS/GestionesService.svc/mex"
         binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
         <identity>
            <dns value="IPADDRESS" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
   </service>      
</services>    

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WSGestiones.GestionesServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://x.x.x.x/GestionesWS/GestionesService.svc" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />          
    </behavior>        

   </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I was able to add the certificate to the trusted list of my PC, I also added to the JDK or wherever in Java.

Some of my errors was:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Cannot find 'https://x.x.x.x/GestionesWS/GestionesService.svc?wsdl' wsdl. Place the resource correctly in the classpath.

HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl)

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong:  should be <x.x.x.x>

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Access Denied
```

Every time I hit an error, searched online and "fixed", a new one appears....in my 5th day of "fixes" I say "this is an infinite loop".

So....instead of trying to fix the errors, I was thinking of "fixing the logic".

Comment: My guess is that Java isn't accepting the certificate as being valid. You may somehow need to add it to a list of trusted certificates before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to connect to a server with a self-signed certificate for a service endpoint via Netbeans.  When I tried to make a new connection object, I came across this runtime exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <hostname as in the certificate>
```

And I finally found a section about this exception in [Metro's documentation](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch12.html#ahicx). The code they provide unfortunately looks like it's intended only to be a temporary solution, but at least it looks like you can get around this issue.

I modified the code they provided by creating a static method that I call at the top of my main method where I always 'verify' the site I connect to for my service:

```
private static void overrideDefaultHostnameVerifier() {
    //WORKAROUND. TO BE REMOVED.
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

The true solution to this problem looks to be getting a real issued certificate on the server hosting the service endpoint.